# When should I update the trial template?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, trialforce

Do I have to create the trial template every time I update the package? we update the package almost on a weekly basis and I feel that this is too much work to create a trial template every time we update the package.

What are our options?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

A trial template should always be the most up to date version of your package. It is what you are using as an ISV Reseller to showcase your product.

With that said, you may not need to update it with every update to your package and can take the following into consideration:

1. Was it a major change
2. Was it a bug fix
3. was the update something someone would notice if they were evaluating your product

number 3 being the most important question.

In addition, keep in mind that when they convert from a trial to a paid customer you may need to have them upgrade the package to the latest version.

Also, you may want to think about not releasing changes so frequently and focus on a release cycle.